# Callback Event for Cordova inAppBrowser

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have an app that access external link through Cordova inAppBrowser.
I want a way to listen to an event when a user returns to the app from the external url.

Currently i can listen to event when inAppBrowser is called like so.

```
        var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
        var myCallback = function(event) { 
                        alert(event.url); 
                    };
       ref.addEventListener('loadstart', myCallback);
```

I want to listen to an event when user returns to the app from the external link.

Answer (score 1):

The load events documented for the InAppBrowser only work with the page you're loading in the InAppBrowser. I'm guessing you want to capture when the user clicks the `done` button and goes back to the app? If thats the case you should look into handling the `exit` event.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {

    function onExit(){
        alert("InAppBrowser Closed!");
    }    

    var inAppBrowser = cordova.InAppBrowser.open("http://apache.org" ,"_blank", "location=yes");

    inAppBrowser.addEventListener('exit', onExit);
}
```